# Is this a regular language? Number of a's greater than $k$

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

> Prove/disprove:
>
> $L = \{ w \mid |w|_a \geq 2k \}$, where $\Sigma = \{ a,b\}$ and $k$ is a constant, is a regular language.

Intuitively I am saying yes, it is a regular language. But I don't seem to find a regular expression for it.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: In PCRE: `/(a|b){2k,}/`  works, doesn't it? I know not all PCREs are regular

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with PCRE.

Comment: All it says is "2k or more elements which are a or b" I'll see if I can work out the grammar though.

Comment: I think that's different from "k or more a in w"...

Comment: It is different.

Comment: Oh sorry I read it wrong

Comment: Wait, is $k$ decided or undecided? ... I understood the problem as "Amount of a's in w is more than or equals to 2k, where k is a fixed constant."

Comment: Isn't this one easy though? If k is constant, we can easily make a finite automaton with 2k states that uses the states as a "counter" up to 2k and verifies that input is in the alphabet. If it reaches the end of the input before it is in a valid state we reject. Recognised by finite automaton, so it is regular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Since k is constant...) `b*ab*a...b*a(a|b)*` where 2k `b*a` is in the expression.

(I don't know how to format this neatly in LaTeX...)

Comment: Yes, thank you! That works!